# .NET Core 3.1 app not reading Azure Pipelines variable

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-pipelines, .net-core-3.1

I've got a .NET Core 3.1 test project, with the following code:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

I then try and access config value, in one of my tests:

```
var storageAcc = configuration["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
```

Works fine on local, as it's using `appsettings.json`, which has the following:

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
}
```

I'm now trying to *override* this in Azure Pipelines, via a variable:
[image]

But when i run the build on CI, my code crashes, saying the value is `null`.

What's strange is this exact setup/code was working fine on .NET Core 2.2, but errored when i upgraded to .NET Core 3.1. So wondering if it's an issue with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` 3.x upgrade path? (can't find anything online)

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, found the answer.

**TLDR; case-sensitivity fail**

I had to change the key in the `appsettings.json` to `AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGE`. I figured this out because when dumping the env vars on Azure Pipelins, i saw the variable was uppercase (note: i am using the `ubuntu` hosted agent, which could play a factor here). So, i guess this wasn't overriding properly if the case was different.

Now, i have **no idea** how this worked on .NET Core 2.2, but doesn't on .NET Core 3.1 (i didn't touch Azure Pipelines, just the SDK for the project). If anyone happens to figure that out, please let me know!

Hope that helps someone. Was pure luck that i figured this out :(